# Dual 4g modems for better (shared) internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, internet-connection, interference, dual-band

At home, I've got a 4g modem (no good internet providers over a phone line or anything else).

This works okay, but sometimes when everyone is home and all using the internet, it can get very slow and ping in games can skyrocket, etc. I was wondering if getting a second separate 4g modem so half of us could use one modem and half could use the other. (maybe one for games where ping is important only or something).

But would this actually help? I've heard that too many devices using the same 2.4ghz or 5ghz band can interfere with each other causing slowdowns. Would having two wifi modems in the same area interfere with each other enough that it wouldn't be worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Networks are designed to be fully utilized without problem. Fully utilizing your 4G link should never cause ping spikes. If it does, it's a pretty good sign your 4G modem is garbage at controlling its backlog of unsent packets when the link is fully utilized (congested). Pitiful queue management like this is a widespread problem in networking equipment, and it's known as bufferbloat.

Run http://dslreports.com/speedtest in a desktop/laptop web browser to check your network's bufferbloat grade.

The solution to bufferbloat is called SQM (Smart Queue Management), and the best SQM algorithm is Cake, followed by FQ-CoDel. Sadly most network equipment vendors are WAY behind on this, so they don't support SQM in their factory firmware. If your networking equipment is supported by an open source Linux router firmware package such as OpenWrt, you could load that on your device and enable Cake SQM there. If that's not an option, you might think about buying an SQM-savvy router and connecting that to your 4G modem via Ethernet, disabling your 4G modem's built-in Wi-Fi AP functionality (if any). One good SQM-savvy router is the IQrouter from evenroute.com. If you do a little online research into bufferbloat, SQM, Cake and FQ-CoDel, you can probably find a few other routers that support SQM.

As for your question about devices in the same area interfering with each other, it's not like you think. It's just that devices on the same channel have to share the airtime by taking turns. The more devices needing airtime on the channel, the smaller the slices of the airtime pie. But adding a second 4G modem probably won't solve the root cause of your ping spikes, if the root cause of your ping spikes is bufferbloat.

Some under-informed but well-meaning people will tell you to use QOS to prioritize gaming traffic over other traffic, but that doesn't solve the problem, it just plops it onto someone else's lap. SQM solves the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if you are limited by bandwidth available over 4G from that provider in your home.  Get a bunch of people with phones on your 4G provider (Verizon for instance).  Get them all in your home and have them turn off wifi.  Ensure that only your desktop is using the 4G modem, and bring up an Internet Speed Test.  On everyone's phone, visit a variety of Internet Speed Tests and keep them going.  It's important that the tests be started at the same time.  Add together everyone's average download speed.  If the total is more than double the rate of your desktop, then you are not constrained by 4G bandwidth.

However, this test is only useful at that time of day, on the day of the week, etc.  Other times in the future, the local 4G spectrum may be crowded by other traffic.  That's hard to predict.

You haven't mentioned in the original question if you use Ethernet or wireless (or both) for your local network.  If you create two separate wireless networks to distribute your two 4G connections, then ensure that they're on different wireless channels.

If you want to do something complicated and you have switch hardware intelligent enough for it, you can perform link aggregation (port trunking) to merge the separate 4G connections into one.  But keep your eyes out for other options - StarLink satellite internet should become operational sometime in 2020.

Comment: yeh we all use wireless. If we use different channels though there is going to be complaints because then who gets the 2.4 band and who gets the better 5ghz band